# An infinite loop appears to have resulted from cross-dependent views

Tags: .net, wpf

In my graphical application, I have a feature to export all pages to images, I have this exception which I don't know where to start looking to solve it:

```
An infinite loop appears to have resulted from cross-dependent views.
```

Any one can help me to get an idea of this exception ? how to solve it ? or what causes such a crash ?

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at KETAB.KStudio.UI.SingleInstanceManager.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in C:\Users\KETAB\Desktop\KStudio.V3.0.0_Official_Before_Gitex\KETABStudio\App.xaml.cs:line 555
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at KETAB.KStudio.UI.SingleInstanceManager.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\KETAB\Desktop\KStudio.V3.0.0_Official_Before_Gitex\KETABStudio\App.xaml.cs:line 536
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's not a lot to go on without any code to look at, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

The first step is to make the views less dependent on each other.  Perhaps have a model that they both look at rather than having them look at each other.

Another step might be making the update code only do an update when needed.  Sometimes, when I have a control that changes another control and I put in logic to update it when the other control changes, I find my update stuff is being called when no change is really needed.  For example, if some event results in the resize of a control, you might want to calculate the new values and then ONLY change the size properties if they have actually changed.  (ie: aren't the same as the new values)

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks, did you encounter the same error message ? can't we tell what would cause the problem ? we are doing virtualizing for the loaded pages, using a view list, when all elements loaded into the page, we capture it, then, we move to the next page .. some times, we render all the pages without problems, but, some times, the bug happens after about 150 page ..

Comment: The problem is that there is no error message.  It's just two windows changing and resulting in each getting updated recursively.  You need to change your event handling on changes such that the changes on one don't cause updates on the other that will in turn update the first window again (and so on and so on..)

Comment: Thanks, We've solved the problem by using do while loop with a wait logic inside ..